# how to set Restemplate Content-type to Empty content

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I need to make a **GET** rest call and I am using restemplate with Spring boot to make the call. The requirement for the request headers is as follows:

Request headers:

1. Content-type  - Empty content
2. Charset - UTF-8
3. Authorization - Basic

Please find piece of code below to implement the above configurations:

```
  public static final String AUTHORISATION = "Authorization";
  public static final String CHARSET = "Charset";
  public static final String BASIC = "Basic";
  public static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";
```

.....

```
ResponseEntity<TransactionResponse> response;
String url =  findTransactionsEndpoint;

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set(Constant.AUTHORISATION, Constant.BASIC);
headers.set(Constant.CHARSET, Constant.UTF8);

HttpEntity<Void> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);


   response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, TransactionResponse.class, transactionRequest);
```

However I don't know how set the Content-type to empty content, any idea how this can be acheived?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you simply omit the header?

Comment: @tgdavies oh you mean not adding content type to the header it should be empty or not specifying header at all I should be able to make the rest call?

Comment: Yes. Please edit your question to explain what error, if any, you are getting when you make the request.

Comment: I don't ve access to the api yet but I am only coding the api call.once I can test it I will post the result.